# WIF SessionSecurityToken Expiration

Tags: azure, .net-4.5, wif, claims-based-identity, acs

I'm trying to implement sliding session expiration. I'm using Windows Azure ACS, .Net 4.5, WIF. When I first receive the token, what I'm doing is setting its default expiration time to 2 hours and write that token into cookie as shown in the code below:

```
internal void SetSession(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    var sessionToken = new SessionSecurityToken(principal, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120));
    FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionToken);
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
}
```

At this time, if I check the `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` properties of the `sessionToken` variable, I get proper values as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Now to implement sliding session expiration, I am handling `SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived` event in my `Global.asax` file as shown below:

```
    void SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived(object sender, SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sessionToken = e.SessionToken;
    }
```

However when I check the `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` properties of the token, it's not what I set when I was writing the token as the cookie as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Not sure why this is happening. Can anybody please explain what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE:**

Here's one interesting thing I noticed. The way I've implemented sliding session is that I check token's `ValidTo` property and compare that with current date/time (in UTC). If the difference is less than 5 minutes, I increase the `ValidTo` time by 2 hours and reissue the cookie as shown in the code below:

```
    void SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived(object sender, SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sessionToken = e.SessionToken;
        var currentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
        var sessionExpirationDateTime = sessionToken.ValidTo.Ticks;
        if (sessionExpirationDateTime >= currentDateTime)
        {
            var renewTokenWindow = 5 * 60 * 1000;//5 minutes
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(sessionExpirationDateTime - currentDateTime);
            if (ts.TotalMilliseconds < renewTokenWindow)
            {
                var newSessionTokenExpiry = sessionToken.ValidTo.AddMinutes(120);
                //Renew token
                SessionAuthenticationModule sam = sender as SessionAuthenticationModule;
                var newSessionToken = sam.CreateSessionSecurityToken(sessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal, sessionToken.Context, sessionToken.ValidFrom, newSessionTokenExpiry, sessionToken.IsPersistent);
                e.SessionToken = newSessionToken;
                e.ReissueCookie = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now after that if I check the value of `ValidTo` property in subsequent requests, it is actually honoring the value I'm setting as shown below. And this value gets persisted request after request i.e. once I reissue the token, everything works well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thinktecture IdentityModel has an implementation, so you can either reference the package via NuGet or you can just copy the source code:

http://brockallen.com/2013/02/17/sliding-sessions-in-wif-with-the-session-authentication-module-sam-and-thinktecture-identitymodel/

Comment: Thanks Brock. However I still don't understand why `ValidTo` value is not set to a value I wanted to. Is it a bug with WIF or I'm doing something incorrect?

Comment: Hi Brock / Gaurav - Did you manage to figure out why the `ValidTo` value was not being set correctly?

Comment: Sorry ... I should have updated the answer long time back. Essentially the default token expiry is set in Windows Azure ACS portal. Whatever value is set there is picked the very first time. HTH.